# generating random characters in C++ for each of three prompts for name

Tags: c++, random, numbers, srand

This program prompts the user to enter in a name. It will then use two while loops. One while loop to generate 3 random letters, followed by a dash followed by another while loop to generate the 3 random digits. I can get the program to do this three times as required.

The problem is it will generate the same three random numbers and letters for each of the three names entered. I would like each name entered to print a unique set of letters and numbers. Is it something with the srand() function?

There is also the problem of adding the dash after printing the characters after the second name is entered  and two dashes after printing the characters for the third name entered.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int nameCount = 0;          // Hold the number of names entered by user
    string randomID;            // Used to concatenate the random ID for 3 names
    string name;                // To hold the 3 names entered by the user
    int numberOfCharacters = 0;
    int numberOfNumbers = 0;
    int a;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while(nameCount < 3) {
        cout << "\nEnter a name: ";
        getline(cin, name);
        while (numberOfCharacters < 3) {
            randomID += static_cast<int>('a') + rand() % 
                (static_cast<int>('z') - static_cast<int>('a') + 1);
            numberOfCharacters++;
        }
        randomID += "-";
        while (numberOfNumbers < 3) {
            randomID += static_cast<int>('1') + rand() %
                (static_cast<int>('1') - static_cast<int>('9') + 1);
            numberOfNumbers++;
        }
        cout << randomID;
        nameCount++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the problem but you can remove all of the static casts in your code.  `static_cast<int>('a') + rand() % 
                (static_cast<int>('z') - static_cast<int>('a') + 1)` is exactly the same as `'a' + rand() % 
                ('z' - 'a' + 1)`.  For why see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions

Comment: Why do you enter a name? Why don't you clear `randomID` after printing it and before re-using it?

Comment: it is just what is required for the assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make `randomID` empty, set `numberOfCharacters` to zero, and set `numberOfNumbers` to zero only once outside the loop. Instead, do this:

```
int main() {
    int nameCount = 0;          // Hold the number of names entered by user
    string name;                // To hold the 3 names entered by the user
    int a;
    srand(time(NULL));
    while(nameCount < 3) {
        string randomID;            // Used to concatenate the random ID for 3 names
        int numberOfCharacters = 0;
        int numberOfNumbers = 0;
        cout << "\nEnter a name: ";
    ...
```

Also:

```
        randomID += static_cast<int>('1') + rand() %
            (static_cast<int>('1') - static_cast<int>('9') + 1);
```

I don't think one minus nine is what you want. Try swapping the 1 and the 9.